# Authorized user's id is empty during unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I face the problem in Laravel 4:

A simple method in the controller:

```
public function getHello()
{
    if( !\Auth::check() ){
        return Redirect::route('user.login');
    }

    //this is working fine just in the web, not for phpunit in the console
    echo \Auth::id();
    //this is working for both
    echo \Auth::user()->id;
}
```

and a simple test case:

```
public function testHello()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $this->be($user);
    $this->action('GET', 'HomeController@getHello');
}
```

I just don't understand why "Auth::id()" returns null/empty string during testing.

Comment: Have you seeded the database with a user?

Comment: @philipbrown yes, second one (\Auth::user()->id) works fine.

Comment: I mean, have you seeded your database during the test?

Comment: @philipbrown why seeding again during the test? I have adjusted the configuration for all environment to use same database, so because auth::user->id is returning correct value, it shows the db connection and seeding has no problem. right?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain what exactly `$this->be()` does, but I'm assuming it creates a `Session` and logs in as `$user`.

If not, then that is the problem.  Sessions are automatically created during web requests, but not during unit tests.

This test isn't actually testing anything, however.  You might want to refactor a bit to expose what is actually happening.

```
public function testHello()
{
    Session::start();
    $user = User::find(1);
    Auth::login($user);
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'HomeController@getHello');
    $this->assertEquals($user->id, $response->getContent());
}
```